# Was Joseph's bad report on his brothers evidence or simply damaging?

Tags: yosef, parashat-vayeishev, lashon-hara-slander, edim-witnesses

"Joseph, being seventeen years old, was feeding the flock with his brethren, being still a lad even with the sons of Bilhah, and with the sons of Zilpah, his father's wives; and Joseph brought evil report of them unto their father." Genesis 37:2 (JPS).

From contemporary views on *halacha*, it seems that it would be bad to report ("speak *lashon hara*") about anyone - even if the issue is a true wrongdoing. Nevertheless, the Torah seems to suggest that we are sometimes required to present evidence of bad behavior to a judge.

Was Joseph speaking *lashon hara* or was he simply giving a factual report to his father, the judge, about something gone bad?

Answer (score 4):

The Shalo Hakadosh ([Parshas Vayeshiev](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9737&pgnum=61)) writes that from the words "ויבא יוסף את דיבתם רעה" (Yosef *brought* evil reports to his father), it seems that Yosef did not fabricate these stories (otherwise it should have said he "made up" the reports).

The Midrash relates that Yosef would tell his father that his brothers were guilty of eating meat that was not slaughtered and engaging in forbidden relationships with women. The Shalo questions how if such stories were true, it could be reconciled with the fact that all twelve sons of Yaakov were holy and righteous.

He brings a fascinating explanation: The brothers would use the secrets of Sefer Yetzirah to create artifical animals and women (golems), which halachically did not require to be slaughtered and were not considered human beings to transgress the laws of illicit relationships. Thus they did not actually transgress anything, but Yosef mistaking them for real people and animals would inform their father. The Chofetz Chaim quotes this story as an illustration of how careful one must be to judge another favorably and avoid lashon hara.

Comment: What about Yosef's accusation "that they demeaned the sons of the handmaids by calling them slaves"( [Rashi on Bereshit 37:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8232/showrashi/true#v2), s.v. "_Et Dibatam Ra'ah_")?

Comment: If Yosef was "mistaking them for real people and animals", does that mean he was "simply giving a factual report to his father, the Judge, about something gone bad"?

Comment: @TamirEvan The Shalo explains this there (I left it out in the answer for the sake of brevity). The brothers rejected the requests of Bilha and Zilpa's sons to join in because one who is not "meyuchas" cannot involve himself in Sefer Yetzirah. However, Yosef was unaware of their motivation.

Comment: @TamirEvan If it was factually incorrect it would be "motzei shem ra". Lashon Harah is telling tales which are true but for no constructive purpose. It seems in this case Yosef was genuinely concerned about his brothers' behaviour, but should still have investigated more thoroughly.

Comment: Doesn't he have to [intentionally] lie( rather than innocently give an incorrect testimony) for it to be _Motzi Shem Ra_? ( See [Mishneh Torah, Hilkhot De'ot 7:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1207.htm#3).)

Comment: This is a fascinating insight. Can you please provide a citation to the work by Shalo HaKadosh?

Comment: Also, is "Shalo HaKadosh" the same as [Shela"h HaQadosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_Horowitz)?

Comment: @Lee I have edited my answer with a link to the original source, and yes we are referring to the same person.

Comment: Related (on the Shalo HaKadosh's interpretation of the indecent): [How did the Shela make the brothers less culpable](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/110382/1368)?