# Animals Created By Sefer Yetzirah

Tags: animals, mysticism-kabbalah, meat-and-milk

[The Malbim explains that someone created a calf using Sefer Yetzirah, and it could then be eaten with milk.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/34923/2699)
What is it about the animals created from Sefer Yetzirah which make it permissible to eat their meat with milk?

Comment: Possibly related, on the subject of _Halakhah_ regarding animals created with _Sefer Yetzirah_: [Michoel's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26405/1368) to "Was Joseph's bad report on his brothers evidence or simply damaging".

Comment: http://torahdoc.free.fr/torahdoc/[1]%20Parasha/Rav%20Friedman/5769/5769-04-Vayeira.pdf Based on this link which explains why the Malchim lost the Torah by eating Basar B'Chalav even though there was no sin on Avraham's part for cooking Basar B'Chalav as the animal was created through Sefer Yetzira. This indicates that there is no issue of Basar B'Chalav by a animal that is created through Sefer Yetzira.

Comment: See Rivevos Ephraim chelek 8:page 27

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rav Betzalel ben Shlomo from Slutzk (1640-1691) in his sefer  עמודיה שבעה [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34449&st=&pgnum=16&hilite=) says:

> An animal which is created using the Sefer Yetzirah, since it was not produced by real flesh and blood parents it is not called flesh and blood at all, but rather it is considered merely air. Therefore, it is not governed by any of the restrictions which apply to normal meat since it is not called meat, and thus can be eaten with milk and is not subject to the laws of אבר מן החי.